# Plot (latitude, longitude) data into a picture

Tags: coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, c++

I have a matrix where en each position I have certain latitude, longitude and each position has a certain value, i.e. amount of rain in that location. I want to plot in C++ the values in an image but right now I am plotting the values based on `rows` and `columns` of my matrix, which  does not reasamble the result I would get mapping the value based on `(longitude, latitude)`.

How can I transform between `(latitude, longitude)` to pixel position in my image?

My objective would be to create some sort of scatter plot where for each transformed (lat,long) I print as a colormap my value.

As I am doing some sort of heatmap I am using a C++ package for that and my current implementation is:

```
void Data::plotImage(int Nx, int Ny, const std::vector<short int>& image, const std::vector<Spherical> &sph, int counter){
    heatmap_t* hm = heatmap_new(Nx, Ny);
    short int value;
    int aprox_row;
    int aprox_column;
    obtainLimitsMap(sph); // gives the maximum/minimum latitude and longitude as max_lat, min_lat, max_long, min_long
    for(int i = 0 ; i < image.size() ; ++i) {
        value = image[i];
        aprox_row = (int)round(Ny*static_cast<double>(sph[i].latitude-min_lat)/(max_lat-min_lat));
        aprox_column = (int)round(Nx*static_cast<double>(sph[i].longitude-min_lat)/(max_lon-min_lon));
        heatmap_add_weighted_point(hm, aprox_column, aprox_row, value); // TODO: Should plot based on (lat,row) not (row,column)
    }
    unsigned char im[Nx*Ny*4];
    heatmap_render_default_to(hm, &im[0]); // Render map into picture
    heatmap_free(hm); // I do not need the map anymore
    writepng("heatmap"+std::to_string(counter)+".png", Nx, Ny, im);
}
```

but the transformation I am making is too simple, just considering max/min longitude and latitude and find the corresponding relationship with the actual point.

Moreover, I do not know whether it helps or not but the data I get from the problem is a matrix with data and 2 formulas to convert each pos from the matrix to spherical `(phi,lambda)`. Then I multiply for 180/pi to get the `(latitude,longitude)` in degrees and now would like to plot it in an image.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what software are you using?

Comment: please specify if your data is gridded or not, i.e. do you have lat/lon coordinate for each cell of a grid or do you have sparse values of lat/long thatarenot on a regular grid (more like points)? Also, please specify the software that you are using (e.g. do you have gdal ?)

Comment: @IanTurton I am working on C++ so would like something that works alongside C++.

Comment: @radouxju I do not know exactl what you mean. All my points are from a similar region so if you plot them in a map they create a square but what I want is the projection onto a picture